# Redirecting in case of a 401 on JWT refreshing

Tags: angular, cookies, jwt, angular9

I'm currently developing an Angular 9 application with JWT authentication on the backend.

I've followed a tutorial that has guided me through making an HTTPInterceptor to refresh my JWT if it is expired, using the refresh token. My tokens reside in server set cookies, and thus do not need to be added to headers.

The code I have for the interceptor is as follows:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
  console.log("Intercepted!");
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log("Error seen");
      if (error && error.status === 401) {
        // 401 errors are most likely going to be because we have an expired token that we need to refresh.
        if (this.refreshing) {
          console.log("Already refreshing");
          // If refreshTokenInProgress is true, we will wait until refreshTokenSubject has a non-null value
          // which means the new token is ready and we can retry the request again
          return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
            filter(result => result !== null),
            take(1),
            switchMap(() => next.handle(req))
          );
        } else {
          this.refreshing = true;

          // Set the refreshTokenSubject to null so that subsequent API calls will wait until the new token has been retrieved
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

          return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
            switchMap((success: boolean) => {
              this.refreshTokenSubject.next(success);
              return next.handle(req);
            }),
            // When the call to refreshToken completes we reset the refreshTokenInProgress to false
            // for the next time the token needs to be refreshed
            finalize(() => this.refreshing = false)
          );
        }
      } else {
        return throwError(error);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

This does the job just fine when refreshing the JWT, but I have another issue that I can't find the answer to.

When my refresh token is expired/missing, I'd like for my Router to redirect to the login page. This essentially happens when a 401 is returned on path `/api/token/refresh`. As you can see, I've added some logs, and when getting from a URL that is protected, this is the output:

```
sendGet
to: /api/test
authconfig.interceptor.ts:27 Intercepted!
GET https://localhost:8000/api/test 401
authconfig.interceptor.ts:30 Error seen
auth.service.ts:43 Refreshing token using refreshtoken from AuthService.
authconfig.interceptor.ts:27 Intercepted!
VM1101:1 GET https://localhost:8000/api/token/refresh 401
authconfig.interceptor.ts:30 Error seen
authconfig.interceptor.ts:34 Already refreshing
```

The interceptor thinks that it is still refreshing, because it never received a proper response from the server from its attempt to refresh the token. Which, if it were a second GET, would be the appropriate response, and I don't know how to differentiate between the two. I've thought of adding a function to check if I am still logged in by GETting from `/api/token/refresh`, but it obviously just gets intercepted and held too.

What is a smart way to go about doing this? I've thought of not having the refresh token in the httponly cookies, so the client can just check if it is still there and conclude that it is no longer authorized, but that seems like a security flaw to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been able to resolve this issue by myself. By checking if the URL for refreshing the token is in the request before putting it in the queue, it is possible to detect that the refresh token is missing. After all, this sequence of events would only occur if a request to the token refreshing path returned a `401`, indicating that there is no token.

If the path of the request contains the URL for token refreshing, we can redirect.